# How to replace a multiple iterator Table to speed up computation

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style, pure-function, slot

I need to create an array of data which resembles to something like this

```
Table[{i, Sin[j^2*i]}, {j, 2000}, {i, 0., Pi, Pi/10000.}]
```

where each "row" of the array contains a list of tuples for varying values of the 'j' parameter. The time required for this computation can be calculated by the `AbsoluteTiming` function, giving

```
{15.1485, Null}
```

I succeeded in using functional programming at the first level. This speeds things up. For example, the following code does the same thing as the initial one:

```
Table[{#1, Sin[j^2 #1]} & /@ Range[0, Pi, Pi/10000.], {j, 2000}]
```

but is 5 times as fast as the original one. `AbsoluteTiming` returns

```
{3.71441, Null}
```

The size of these tables roughly represents the size of the data that I am currently manipulating (lots of it). Since I noticed that `Table` is not the most "time-efficient" option, I would like to learn how to construct this kind of table with things like pure functions and slots (which I naively assume leads to faster code).

Comment: `Table[{i, Sin[j^2 i]}, {j, 2}, {i, 0., Pi, Pi/100.}];` : `Table` can take multiple iterators.

Comment: @Syed You are right and I do not know why but I was evaluating a Table with the iterators in the wrong order, which of course was not giving the desired result: `Table[{i, Sin[j*i]}, {i, 0., 4 Pi, 4 Pi/100.},{j,2}]`. Nevertheless, I have modified the title and updated my question accordingly.

Comment: `t1 = Chop@Table[{i, Sin[j*i]}, {j, 2}, {i, 0., 4 Pi, 4 Pi/100.}];` and `t2 = Chop@
   Outer[{#2, Sin[#1 #2]} & , {1, 2}, Range[0., 4 Pi, 4 Pi/100.]];` are almost identical in timing.

Comment: `Table` _is_ functional programming. If what you are looking for is to speed up this code, then please edit the question and make that the main topic.

Comment: @Szabolcs I got confused with what functional programming means. You are right, speed is what I am looking for. The question has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, upvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set

```
A=N[Range[2000]];
B=N[Range[0,Pi,Pi/10000.]];
```

I will compare

```
method1:=Outer[{#2,Sin[#1^2*#2]}&,A,B];
method2:=Transpose[{ConstantArray[B,Length[A]],
                    Sin[Outer[Times,A^2,B]]},{3,1,2}];
```

To check that they give the same output, run

```
Max[Abs[Flatten[method1-method2]]]
```

Timing

```
RepeatedTiming[method1;]
(* about 27 seconds *)

RepeatedTiming[method2;]
(* about 0.7 seconds *)
```

So `method2` is quite a bit faster. The reason is that it uses [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496) and certain simple constructs such as `Outer[Times,...]` that are fast.

**Comment.** Perhaps there is some room for further improvement, but I would think that one limitation is `Sin`. Therefore, I would be surprised if there was a solution faster than

```
temp=RandomReal[{-1,1},Length[A]*Length[B]];
RepeatedTiming[Sin[temp];]
(* about 0.1 seconds *)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you have a wrong square: A^2. It should only be: A

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for your feedback. OPs question contains both versions, one without square and one with square, and I thought I take the one with square.